# How to loop over different values in SQL and create a new row for it?

Tags: sql

I have the following table of data:

| Item | BasePrice | Price | PriceList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | - |
| B | 1 | 1 | - |
| C | 1.5 | 1.5 | - |
| D | 1.5 | 1.5 | - |
| A | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| B | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| A | 1 | 1.25 | 02 |
| C | 1.5 | 1.25 | 02 |
| D | 1.5 | 1.25 | 03 |

When you sort this data on item, you see:

| Item | BasePrice | Price | PriceList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | - |
| A | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| A | 1 | 1.25 | 02 |
| B | 1 | 1 | - |
| B | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| C | 1.5 | 1.5 | - |
| C | 1.5 | 1.25 | 02 |
| D | 1.5 | 1.5 | - |
| D | 1.5 | 1.25 | 03 |

It give a good overview on price per pricelist.

Now I want to query the items per pricelist. The thing is, the items without a pricelist need to be in every result if there is not specific pricelist entry, with the value of the price that is the baseprice.

I would like the resulting data to look like this:

| Item | BasePrice | Price | PriceList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | - |
| A | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| A | 1 | 1.25 | 02 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 03 |
| B | 1 | 1 | - |
| B | 1 | 1.5 | 01 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 02 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 03 |
| C | 1.5 | 1.5 | - |
| C | 1.5 | 1 | 01 |
| C | 1.5 | 1.25 | 02 |
| C | 1.5 | 1 | 03 |
| D | 1.5 | 1 | - |
| D | 1.5 | 1 | 01 |
| D | 1.5 | 1 | 02 |
| D | 1.5 | 1.5 | 03 |

So essentially, if I query for a pricelist, I get ALL items that exist returned, filled with baseprices if they were not in the queried pricelist.

I cannot get my head around the query. I tried to work with Joins but I end up with multiple columns. I think there is an easier way.

PS the number of available pricelists is dynamic.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Loops are the wrong way to do basically anything in RDBMS. Think in terms of datasets. Operations should produce results for all members of a dataset. If you don't need a member in a dataset or need to control the matches, use a `WHERE` clause or restrict your `JOIN` criteria. If you need a loop to solve a problem, your data design needs to be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database design is not good. You are storing the base price in the price list although there is only one base price per item. This redundancy violates database normalization, and you should change it before running into any issues.

Here are three normalized tables (primary keys italic):

- items (*item_no*, name, base_price, ...)
- price_lists (*price_list_no*, purpose, ...)
- prices (*item_no, price_list_no*, price, ...)

Then to the task: You want one result row per item and price list. You get this by cross joining all items with all price lists. Then outer join the price table.

```
select
  i.item_no,
  i.base_price,
  coalesce(p.price, i.base_price) as price
  pl.price_list_no,
from items i
cross join price_lists pl
left outer join prices p on p.item_no = i.item_no
                         and p.price_list_no = pl.price_list_no
order by i.item_no, i.base_price;
```

Comment: This is very insightfull. I think I can create these tables. Lets try this route!

Comment: This worked like a charm!
Is there a way to add all products without a pricelist as well, so I can query where 'pricelist' is null ? 
The cross-join is it.